Pycoin/Python spending part UTXO
I have a little App for me that uses the xpub to scan for all received coins. I am using Blockchain to collect the info. This is working fine, now I am facing the issue that when coins are spent, i have a wrong balance if i just spend part of my utxo. I looked into the outputs, how can I figure out what was payed to myself? the json looks not different for the outputs. can i check if the address is part of my xpub?
Edit
It is an Extend Public Key as a zpub

Are you asking about spending part of one UTXO or a subset of your UTXOs? A single UTXO cannot be spent partially. All UTXO are spent completely and the remainder must be assigned to a change output to be returned to the sender. Also see How does change work in a bitcoin transaction?

In Pycoin you have to change the parmeter in the subkey method, the account type
 xpub = network.parse(key)
 lookup(xpub, 0)
 lookup(xpub, 1)

Like this you will get all address from your xpub where bitcoin where sent to.
